# How do I prevent(filter) WM_MOUSEMOVE from affecting WM_TIMER case statement evaluating true

Tags: winapi, freebasic

I am using FreeBASIC with win32API to make a simple data logger. I have an EditBox inside the Main window displaying data-log records 1 per second.

It all works perfectly, except when I move the mouse between the Main window & the EditBox (specifically the lower & right edge, where the scroll bars would be or are displayed), then I get extra 2 timer events evaluated true in my `case` statement with each move. (WindowMain to EditBox or EditBox to WindowMain).

Is there a way to filter the message from (I assume) `WM_MOUSEMOVE` making the Timer Case code evaluate True?

Edit1: I can confirm the WM_TIMER event message is activated when the mouse moves in/out of the area of the Editbox ScrollBars.
Disabling ScrollBar arrows does not mitigate the issue.(just disables the ScrollBars)
EnableScrollBar(LogWindow,SB_BOTH,ESB_DISABLE_BOTH)

Edit2: Now that I have identified the specific cause of my issue, the title of this question is not right. The unwanted WM_TIMER messages are from the EditBox scroll bars, there would be a timer associated with mouse over.

Code:

```
SetTimer(Window_Main, 1, 1000, 0 )  
                      '                             
 Do     'Main loop to check WinAPI event states:

   WaitEvent(Window_Main, msg)
'- Select Case msg.hwnd
   Select Case msg.message
      Case WM_TIMER                          
         If LogState = Run_ Then Get_Data
'        Get_Data  '<<<-- DEBUG ONLY to test timer

   End Select

   Select Case msg.hwnd
      Case Btn_TstCom
         If msg.message = WM_LBUTTONUP Then
            EditBox_Paste(LogWindow)
         End If

      Case Btn_ClrLog
```

[image]

Comment: You have the HWND and ID of the timer in the `WM_TIMER` message, make sure they match your timer before you process the message.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to get the ID '1' of the WM_TIMER using an If statement inside the 'Case WM_TIMER'. Looking at various resources & sample code for the timer [eg https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/petzold/ch08c.htm] .                In the interim I just test the time elapsed, If its greater than LogPeriod then I respond to the WM_TIMER message.

Comment: It is entirely likely for a standard edit control to install a timer (e.g., for the blinking caret animation). As pointed out already, you need to distinguish your `WM_TIMER` from all other timer messages (see [A window can’t have two timers with the same ID, so how do I assign an ID that nobody else is using?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191009-00/?p=102974)). Timers that aren't yours need to get passed on to the system for default processing.

Comment: My crystal ball says that WaitEvent is actually a function.  With a return value that indicates that a message was in fact available.  So the second time you call it, after receiving a timer message, it returns nothing but *msg* still has the previous value.  You can't see that because of the missing return value check.

Comment: @IInspectable , That sounds like whats happening, I bet the scroll bar uses a timer & I am responding to all timer events.  I set the ID but not able to filter it YET, more reading... _____ Hans,  It is a real wait event that halts the Do Loop until a WM event , I verified this earlier when I had subroutine call inside this loop & it only ran when I moved the mouse.  Other w32api event stuff is working ok (buttons, resize).

Comment: The `msg` structure presumably has a field called `wParam`. For `WM_TIMER` messages, this field holds the timer ID you can use to identify your timer. As for the remaining scenarios that work, they do so because they never go through your message loop: Button controls send non-queued messages, and resize operations spin up a nested message loop.

Answer (score 0):

With some help on a forum, adding the following filtered just the message from the timer in my `SetTimer` statement:

```
If msg.hwnd = Window_Main AndAlso msg.wParam = 1 Then
```

Here, `msg.wParam` is the Timer ID.